# Is there an API to clear the terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a VSCode extension. I don't see any API to clear the terminal. Am I missing something or does it need to be implemented?

I tried looking through the VSCode reference docs, but was not able to find anything helpful.

Comment: As far as I can see it's not implemented yet, the issue is still open. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17895

Answer (score 2):

Philipp Kief is correct that there is no official API. As noted, 
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17895 tracks adding this

If you absolutely need this functionality, try using the `workbench.action.terminal.clear` command to clear the active terminal:

```
import { commands } from 'vscode';
commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.terminal.clear');
```

Comment: FWIW, note that `workbench.action.terminal.clear` clears all of the terminal output, not just what's in view.